# Minimize $(x+y)(x+z)$ with constraint without calculus

Tags: inequality, optimization

> Let $x,y,z \in \mathbb R^+$ such that $xyz\cdot(x+y+z) = 1$
>
> Find $\min\{(x+y)(x+z)\}.$

Using calculus, and Lagrange multipliers, I get:

$(x+y)(x+z) \ge2$ (with the equality occurring if and only if $y=z=1,\ x=\sqrt{2} - 1$).

But I want to solve it in an easy way, which doesn't need calculus.

How can I do it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: Your expression is $x(x+y+z)+yz= 1/yz+yz$

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Recall the Heron's formula for triangle. Let $y+z=a, z+x=b, x+y=c$, then the problem becomes given the area to minimize $bc$.

Answer (score 0):

By AM-GM
$$(x+y)(x+z)=x(x+y+z)+yz\geq2\sqrt{xyz(x+y+z)}=2.$$
The equality occurs for $xyz(x+y+z)=1$ and $x(x+y+z)=yz$,

which says that the equality indeed occurs, which gives the answer: $2$.